# in pydantic.validators.find_validators TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class

Tags: python, pydantic

Hello I am reading a JSON with the following format:

```json
{
    "1": {"id":1, "type": "a"},
    2: {"id":2, "type": "b"},
    "3": {"id":3, "type": "c"},
    "5": {"id":4, "type": "d"}
}
```

As you can see the keys are numbers but are not consecutives.

So I have the following `BaseModel` to the nested `dict`:

```py
@validate_arguments
class ObjI(BaseModel):
    id: int
    type: str
```

The question is how can I validate that all items in the `dict` are `ObjI` without use of:

```py
objIs = json.load(open(path))
assert type(objIs) == dict
    for objI in objIs.values():
        assert type(objI) == dict
        ObjI(**pair)
```

I tried with:

```py
@validate_arguments
class ObjIs(BaseModel):
    ObjIs:  Dict[Union[str, int], ObjI]
```

EDIT

The error validating the previous is:

```
in pydantic.validators.find_validators TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could change your model definitions to use a [*custom root type*](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#custom-root-types) (no need for the `validate_arguments` decorators):

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Dict

class ObjI(BaseModel):
    id: int
    type: str

class ObjIs(BaseModel):
    __root__: dict[int, ObjI]
```

The model can now be initialised with the JSON data, e.g. like this:

```py
import json
with open("/path/to/data") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

objis = ObjIs.parse_obj(data)
```

If `data` contains invalid types (or has missing fields), `prase_obj()` will raise a `ValidationError`.
For examples, if `data` looked like this:

```py
data = {
    "1": {"id": "x", "type": "a"},
#                ^
#                wrong type
    2: {"id": 2, "type": "b"},
    "3": {"id": 3, "type": "c"},
    "4": {"id": 4, "type": "d"},
}

objs = ObjIs.parse_obj(data)
```

it would result in:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for ObjIs
__root__ -> 1 -> id
  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
```

which tells us that the `id` of the object with key `1` has an invalid type.

(You can catch and handle a `ValidationError` like any other exception in Python.)

(The pydantic [docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#custom-root-types) also recommend to implement custom `__iter__` and `__getitem__` methods on the model if you want to access the items in the `__root__` field directly.)

Comment: Hi paul the question is about nested object, I don't want to se thtat like an array because root key is a database ID and is not consecutive, is then possible?

Comment: @Tlaloc-ES - Sorry about the delay, I've updated the solution now.